# Python - subprocess.popen - play mp4 using it's path

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

**What is the problem I am facing-** I am trying to run an mp4 from a file path using subprocess.popen.

**Details -** I originally tried:
os.system - it works but it doesn't take a variable of a string. Or I am not converting my variable into a string correctly. I will show example pictures below.

`subprocess.call` - I couldn't get this to run an mp4 from vlc (I have to use call as I have to use python 2.7.18. I know its old but I am stuck on that for the program I am trying to use this with)
`subprocess.popen` - I was able to get `subprocess.popen` to open up vlc player, but I wasn't able to make it run an mp4 using vlc. I am not sure if this is an argument issue or I am just not show how to write this correctly.

**Main goal -** I am trying to make a script where it asks me what I would like to search on my computer, and after I input what I would like to search it find the first thing it sees, then runs it. I am using `os.walk` to find the first file in my search, and I can print it, but I can't execute from the path value it finds.

My current code:

```
import os
import subprocess
def find(name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/RKerrigan/Videos/w\\', followlinks=True):
        for file in files:
            if name in file:
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                print(music)
                subprocess.popen([vlc])
                return
    print("Finish")
try:
    s=raw_input("name: ")
    find(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error")
```

**Pictures of the issue -**

Me trying `subprocess.popen` in a very simple script to see if I can run a mp4 from a file path
[image]

Me trying `subprocess.popen` in a very simple script but using a variable for the path of the file. VLC will open but no `mp4` will open. Only the base program.
[image]

Me trying `subprocess.popen` in the full script I am working on. I am using `os.walk` to find the first file it can, then I am trying to print it and run the actual file it finds. However Only VLC opens, no file.
[image]

Me trying `os.system` in the full script I am working on. I like `os.system` as it works when I put in a string to the file path. It will run an `mp4` no problem but when I try to get the value of what I search using `os.walk` and use that as the path of the file it doesn't execute. Furthermore it doesn't give an errors like `subprocess.popen` does.
[image]

Me trying `os.system` but trying the `str` function to turn a value into a string for use. - It still didn't work for me or I am doing it wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a close look at this part:

```
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                print(music)
                subprocess.popen([vlc])
```

During each iteration of the loops, you've assign the same string to the `vlc` variable, `'C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'`, making the `subprocess.popen([vlc])` call do the exact same thing each time.

The logical thing to do is *use* the discovered path, `music`, inside the [`popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) call:

```
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(root,file))
                print(music)
                subprocess.popen([vlc, music])
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! I actually had did [vlc, music] but it didn't work at first. I didn't know why but then I looked through vlc and realized that it was looking at the path with \ slashes instead of / slashes.

I changed the popen to ([vlc, music]) then had os.walk using C:/ instead of C:\ and it worked. 

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass second argument to popen

```
subprocess.popen([vlc, music])
```

Docs here https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's better to link [up-to-date versions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) of python documentations.